# error occur after importing existing project in eclipse ide

Tags: eclipse, maven

Problem Occurred
'reload maven project' has encountered a problem.

An internal error occurred during: "reload maven project".
Error reading class bytes:
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.TransferEvent

by deleting the .settings folder and .project file in the project and then reimporting the project doesn't work for me.

Could you help me? Thank you.